# Adding array to existing $_SESSION array

Tags: php, arrays, session

I got following existing array in my `$_SESSION`:

```
[wishList] => wishList Object
(
[contents] => Array
(
[109] => Array
(
[qty] => 1.0000
)

[89] => Array
(
[qty] => 1.0000
)

[62] => Array
(
[qty] => 1.0000
)
```

Now i am trying to add a new object to it like this:

```
echo $_SESSION['wishList']->contents = array('60' => array('qty' => '1.0000'));
```

So the array would look like this:

```
[wishList] => wishList Object
    (
    [contents] => Array
    (
    [109] => Array
    (
    [qty] => 1.0000
    )

    [89] => Array
    (
    [qty] => 1.0000
    )

    [62] => Array
    (
    [qty] => 1.0000
    )

    [60] => Array
    (
    [qty] => 1.0000
    )
```

It is not working the way i try it. Where is my fault?

Comment: Are you getting any sort of error message?

Comment: nope, there is no error message.

Comment: @A-2-A I did not yet, i had no time left yesterday, but i will in the next few hours, don't worry, i will accept one as right answer if it works :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tr this:-

```
array_push($_SESSION['wishList']->contents,array('60' => array('qty' => '1.0000')));
```

Or try this :-

```
array_push($_SESSION['wishList']->contents[$pid] = array('qty' => '1.0000')); // where $pid = 60;
```

Comment: This is the working solution, this does exactly what i need. Thank you. Little Edit to your code: You are missing a ")" at the end before the semi-colon.

Comment: i had to edit the code a bit more as i thought first, but your answer brought me on the right track, this is how it works now:  array_push($_SESSION['wishList']->contents[$pid] = array('qty' => '1.0000'));

Answer (score 0):

```
$_SESSION['wishList']->wishList['contents'] = "your new value string or array";
```

you missed out selecting main object.

i tried a piece of code. which works for me.

```
session_start();
class newObject {
    var $aProp  = array("type1"=>"test1", "type2"=>"test2");
    function __contruct() {
        return array("type1"=>"test1", "type2"=>"test2");
    }
}
$newObject  = new newObject;
$_SESSION["newObj"] = $newObject;
print_r($_SESSION);
// prints Array ( [newObj] => newObject Object ( [aProp] => Array ( [type1] => test1 [type2] => test2 ) ) ) 
echo "<br>";
$_SESSION["newObj"]->aProp  = array("type3"=>"test3", "type4"=>"test4");
// prints Array ( [newObj] => newObject Object ( [aProp] => Array ( [type3] => test3 [type4] => test4 ) ) )
print_r($_SESSION);
```

according to me.. what you have missed is pointing out the correct target. here in your case it is `$_SESSION['wishList']->wishList['contents']`

Answer (score 0):

```
$_SESSION['wishList']->contents[60] = array('qty' => '1.0000');
```

This changes the array `$_SESSION['wishList']->contents` by setting its value at index `60` to the array.

Comment: An elaboration to your answer would definitely help others to understand better than a single command-line.